# Do find_elements_by_* functions always reflect DOM order?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Does a call like `browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('input[type=text]')` always return `WebElement` objects in the order that reflects the DOM?

I ask because I have a to-do list-like application and the order that form elements appear on the page (added dynamically) is vital, and perhaps I'm being anal but I'm testing this behaviour as part of my test suite.

N.B.: I'll likely run the test in a variety of browsers.

My test (Python with `unittest`):

```
def test_titles_should_appear_in_the_order_they_are_entered(self):
    titles = ['title 1', 'title 2', 'title 3']
    for title in titles:
        self._type_new_title(title).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    inputs = self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('input[type=text].title')
    # assumption: inputs will always reflect the DOM order, top to bottom
    input_vals = [i.get_attribute('value') for i in inputs]
    self.assertEqual(input_vals, titles)
```

Comment: Anecdotally speaking, I have only ever seen the returned elements order match that of their DOM position. Otherwise when I make a list of elements and I specify `list[0]` I'm just REALLY lucky that it fetches the same element time after time.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this is true, which also makes sense, in that the FindElements methods are going to parse the document looking for matches based on the locator.

Additionally, even if they aren't exactly in the DOM order, it will be consistent each time, so you should be safe to write your test accordingly.

However, keep in mind that anytime you use order on multiple matches, that if you add or remove inputs, then that order is likely to change, and you'll need to update the test accordingly.

Comment: "even if they aren't exactly in the DOM order, it will be consistent each time" -will it be consistent between browsers?

Comment: In my experience, yes.  The WebDriver javascript atoms used to locate the elements should be the same for each of the driver implementations, which means it should be consistent.